# Symfony KnpGaufretteBundle with alias

Tags: symfony, alias

So I have my KnpGaufretteBundle configured like this:

```
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        local_shared:
            local:
                directory: "%shared.dir%"
                create: false
    filesystems:
        local_shared:
            adapter: local_shared
            alias: defaul_fs
```

Then I need to inject it to my own service, I do this:

```
acme.user_manager:
  class: %acme_user.user_manager.class%
  arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @security.context]
  calls:
      - [setFilesystem, [@default_fs]]
```

But this breaks with exception `The service definition "default_fs" does not exist.`

If I use `@gaufrette.local_shared_filesystem` as a parameter instead of `@default_fs` then it works like expected. But I would like to use an alias.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you noticed that you have a typo in your config declaration:

```
alias: defaul_fs
```

has no "t"